# How to remove more than one space from selected text?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

for example

this ( see space between word, space after fullstop and space before fullstip)

```
We prefer questions that    can be answered, not just discussed.    We prefer questions that can be answered, not just   discussed  .   We prefer   questions that can be answered, not just discussed   .
```

to this

**We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHK has regex support - as such, a quick expression:

```
^!v::
clipboard:=ClipboardAll
output:=RegexReplace(clipboard, "\s\s+", " ")
output:=RegexReplace(output, "\s([.])", "$1")
sendraw %output%
Return
```

This hotkey fires on Control-Alt-V. The ^ is control, the ! is alt, and the v is, well, v. Easy to change if you'd like something that doesn't require two hands :)

Hardcoding the . in isn't exactly elegant.
The proof: We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

**Edit:** There, AHK does support $1. That ([.]) means "match any of the characters within the []s (in this case... just .), and the brackets mean store what it finds, so it can output it for the $1. The upshot of this is that if you stick other punctuation marks inside that [], they'll be auto-despaced too.

Comment: how to use this script , i mean what is keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Control(^) Alt(!) v(v). Sorry for not making that clear - I assumed you were used to using AHK, as it was tagged in the question. I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: good working , but it rewrote whole text again.

Comment: Sendraw does that, yeah. You can change the timing with `SetKeyDelay`, but there's no real need.

Answer (score 1):

you could use notepad, and replace two spaces with one. :)

Comment: That's how I usually do it.  Then just keep doing it until none are found.  Simple concept that works in just about any editor that has search & replace. ;)  I +1'd you for suggesting Notepad when it was plain text that was presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find and replace feature in word.

In 2003:

1. go to the "Edit" menu
2. Choose "Replace"
3. In "Find What", type two spaces
4. In "Replace With" type one space
5. Then click "Replace All"

Comment: Does it hang around afterwards? If so, a couple of presses would work for 3+ spaces!